# Query Posts depends on custom field inside repeater field using acf

Tags: wp-query, post-meta, advanced-custom-fields

i am working on a hotel website and trying to make price search

i have custom post type name hotels inside post type i have a [repeater field](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/repeater/)
inside repeater i have some rooms with prices 
[image: rooms inside custom post type]

i am trying to search throw this prices

the code which i tried

```
$args = array( 
'post_type' => 'hotels',
'posts_per_page' => 4,
'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
'meta_query'    => array(
'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'key'       => 'room_price',
        'compare'   => '<=',
        'type'      => 'NUMERIC',
        'value'     => 200

    ),
    array(
        'key'       => 'room_price',
        'compare'   => '>=',
        'type'      => 'NUMERIC',
        'value'     => 100

    ),
),
'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'country',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => $cat,
        'compare' => 'IN',
    ),
)

);
```

and i got nothing i think this issue because the field inside a repeater field but i cant figure out the solution